# Mongo query to remove "\n" from all _index fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

I am using mongomapper with my rails app. It errors whenever a mongo entry has "\n" in the "_index" or any of the fields.

> SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting
>   tCOLON2 or '.' (eval):3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end,
>   expecting $end

The reason the fields have "\n" is because the data was scraped and not properly cleaned.

For example this is one of the problem fields:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > Activity.where(:_index => /\n/i).first["_index"]
 => "Heating Building\n\nAir Emissions"
```

To fix this in ruby (mongoid) it would basically be:

```
Activity.where(:_index => /\n/i).each do |a|
  a.update_attribute(:_index, a[:_index].gsub("\n", " "))
end
```

Is there a way I can do this fix just using a mongo query?

The mongo query would need to go through every mongo row and replace "\n" with " " in the _index field.

The reason I ask is that we don't have time to move our app from mongomapper to mongoid (mongoid knows how to handle \n without erroring).

Comment: The code you've written should work in MongoMapper too, using `find_each` and a standard change/save instead of update_attribute.  Though note if the documents get bigger when you save them you might get some docs back twice http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+do+Snapshotted+Queries+in+the+Mongo+Database

Answer (score 3):

You were looking for this:

```
   db.activities.find({_index:/\n/}).forEach(function(obj) { obj._index = obj._index.replace(/\n/g, ' '); db.activities.save(obj);});
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.eval()` is probably what you're looking for.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D